# Bug report tool on aws

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, bug-tracking

I'm developing a mobile app and i have to add a "report bug" feature. User can write something wrong he notices in the app and when he pushes, we collect the smartphone metatadata, app version, etc...So we have a json report ready to be send.
For the moment we don't know where store this report data, which tool to use ? We are using aws cloud, and are looking over internet to know if aws provide such bug tracker tool.

If not what tool could we use to achieve this use case ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: DynamoDB table so you can query it.

Comment: The answer depends on how you want to _use_ the data once it is stored somewhere. If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Comment: There's no specific service for this as far as I'm aware.  What are your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find a list of tools used to track user bugs and report:

https://instabug.com/

https://raygun.com/languages/android

https://raygun.com/languages/android